# PreventDefault alternative for IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, preventdefault

**Situation**: Trying to modify VideoJS.com in order to work with IE8 and Youtube Chromeless API.

**Problem**: Progressbar dragging doesn't work (error on event.preventDefault(); 'not supported' according to debug)

**Demo**: http://alpha.dealertouch.mobi/video/demo.html

**What I tried**: Skip 'preventDefault' when it's IE, but if I do that I'll lose the functionality of the progressbar (drag/click forward and backward)

**Question**: What is the best way to solve this problem for IE8?

Answer (score 29):

I use something like:

```
(event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

the `event.returnValue` property is the closest IE equivalent to `preventDefault`.

Using

```
return false;
```

can sometimes also work, but it can lead to unexpected behavior sometimes when mixed with e.g. jQuery (jQuery also does `stopPropagation`...which is **usually** what you want, but...), so I prefer not to rely on it.

Answer (score 5):

IE8 does not support `preventDefault`; it has `returnValue` instead. jQuery should normalize that for you, though. Are you sure you are calling `preventDefault` on the jQuery event wrapper (and not the actual event object)?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
return false;
```

it's cross browser and has the same purpose as event.preventDefault();

THe same instruction in jQuery is slightly different, it includes also stopPropagation().

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false for a caveat of this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
$('.selector').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
```

[jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: As stated in the question, which is even titled "PreventDefault alternative for IE8" this does not work in IE8.

Comment: @Purrell this was a old question that was edited since my answer, thanks for your opinion...