# Why this javascript function not work on ie7 and 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Why this javascript function not work on ie7 and 8 ?

When user click button , it's will display `PLEASE WAIT....` and hide and then display `TEST`

I test on firefox and chrome, It's OK

But not work on IE7 and 8 , How can i do that ?

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" name="send_ask" action="test_e.php" method="post">
    <button id="sub">Send</button>
    <span id="loading" style="display:none;">PLEASE WAIT.......</span>
    <span id="result" style="display:none;"></span>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        data: $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            document.getElementById("sub").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display="inline";
            $("#result").hide()
        },
        complete: function(data){
            $("#result").show()
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

test_e.php

```
TEST
```

Comment: What happens in IE? Are there any console errors?

Comment: in ie not show/hide text.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422045/preventdefault-alternative-for-ie8

Comment: it may not be showing because of an error. Open your dev tools and see what the console says (most browsers support `<F12>` as the keyboard shortcut to open the dev tools)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first thing I see if the button is not a submit button so not sure how the others are submitting the form.

```
<button id="sub" type="submit">Send</button>
```

Comment: If a button is inside a form, it will trigger a submit even without `type="submit"` unless it's explicitly set to `type="button"`. Odd but true!