# Disable drop and dragover event in internet explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, drag-and-drop

I would like to disable the option to drag and drop files to a webpage in IE 8.
Currently the behavior is that IE 8 tries to open the file.

I am using JQuery and this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('drop dragover', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // for everything else - this works but not for IE 8
        e.returnValue = false; // for IE 8 - but this does not work
    });
});
```

update:

```
$(document).on('drop dragover', function(e) {
            if(e.preventDefault){
                e.preventDefault(); // for everything else - this works but not for IE 8
            }
            else{
                e.returnValue = false; // for IE 8 - but this does not work
            }
```

jsfiddle for Chrome to prove this works:
https://jsfiddle.net/07qgw36b/

Comment: Are you using a 1.x or 2.x version of jQuery?  Browser compatibility might be the issue: https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Jquery 1.11.1, the one that works with ie8.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`(event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;`

Maybe it is not getting the the `event.returnValue` line because `e.preventDefault()` comes back undefined.

[PreventDefault alternative for IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422045/preventdefault-alternative-for-ie8)